# about required memory size in ATmega32 to execute a certain program

Tags: arduino-uno, c, avr

If I want to add two numbers and print the output on LCD

```
char answer[8];
float a=5.1,b=3.2,c;
c=a+b;
 dtostrf(c,8,3,answer);//convert float to ASCII to print it on LCD
for(i=0;i<8;i++) Lcd8_Write_Char(answer[i]);
```

What is the required memory space to execute this program?

Comment: You can't execute that program. It's incomplete. Also it's not easy to second guess the optimizer in the compiler. All I can say is "at least 8 plus whatever `i` needs and maybe `a` `b` and `c` if they don't get optimized out".  So between 8 and 24 bytes plus anything else the rest of the program will need.

Comment: You can easily find out the size of a program and the needed RAM, by writing a full program (with `void setup()` and `void loop()`) and compile it in the Arduino IDE. It will tell you, what you want to know

Comment: @chrisl afaik local variables and stack size are not taken into account while compiling, so one needs to use the SRAM size mentioned by the compiler + the maximum amount / deepest stack flow arguments usage + local variables.

Comment: You can use the utility freeRAM https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory/ to check what the compilation can't tell you. Besides, your variable `answer`is too small by 1 (the trailing `\0` )